# Invisible the button by using attrs tag in odoo 9 xml

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I am trying to invisible the button but its not working, Why its like this?

```
<button name="%(sale_confirm_details)d" states="draft" type="action" attrs="{'invisible':[('order_confirm','=',True)]}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following

```
          <record model="ir.ui.view" id="form_view_id_inherit">
                <field name="name">model.name.form</field>
                <field name="model">model.model</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.form_view_id"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <data>
                        <xpath expr="//button[@name='sale_confirm_details']" position="attributes">
                            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>                                                       
                        </xpath>
                    </data>
                </field>
            </record>
```

Comment: Its a custom button, not a inherited one.

Comment: Did u set the default value for this order_confirm filed as True or False?